# How to properly use Nan::HandleScope?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, native, abstraction

I'm writing a c++ addon for node using NAN, but I'm confused how to correctly use Nan::HandleScope (https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/scopes.md#api_nan_handle_scope)

In my application I'm doing something like this (error checking removed, and only simplified version of code is shown):

```
static App* s_pApp = nullptr;

NAN_METHOD( init ) {
  s_pApp = new App();
} 

NAN_METHOD( getData ) {
  info.GetReturnValue().Set( s_pApp->getData() );
}

NAN_METHOD( close ) {
  delete s_pApp;
  s_pApp = nullptr;
}

//-------- This create a new json object based on the current state of _pRootNode which is a TreeNode class object previously populated
v8::Local<v8::Object> App::getData() const {
    Nan::EscapableHandleScope scope;
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = _pRootNode->getData();
    return scope.Escape( obj ); 
}

//-------- The TreeNode class 
v8::Local<v8::Object> TreeNode::getData() const {
  return getData( this );
}

//each node contains data plus a vector of children that are also TreeNodes
v8::Local<v8::Object> TreeNode::getData( const TreeNode* pNode ) const {
  v8::Local<v8::Object> jsonObject = Nan::New<v8::Object>();

  addProperty( jsonObject, "isImportant", _isImportant );
  addProperty( jsonObject, "value", _value );
  addProperty( jsonObject, _children );

  return jsonObject;
}

//The addProperty functions are used to populate the jsonObject which will eventually be returned back to JavaScript
template<class T>
void TreeNode::addProperty( v8::Local<v8::Object>& jsonObject, const char* szName, T propValue ) {
  v8::Local<v8::String> prop = Nan::New( szName ).ToLocalChecked();
  v8::Local<v8::Value> value = getValue( propValue ); //returns the appropriate v8 value
  Nan::Set( jsonObject, prop, value );  
}

void TreeNode::addProperty( v8::Local<v8::Object>& jsonObject, const std::vector<const TreeNode*>& children ) {
  if( children.empty() ) {
    return;
  }

  v8::Local<v8::String> prop = Nan::New( "children" ).ToLocalChecked();

  v8::Local<v8::Array> values = Nan::New<v8::Array>( children.size() );
  for( int i = 0, numChildren = children.size(); i < numChildren; ++i ) {
    values->Set( i, children.at( i )->getData() ); //recursive call
  }

  Nan::Set( jsonObject, prop, values );  
}
```

So as we can see in the code above, The only place that I'm handling scope is in the App::getData() call which returns the json object that is created by the TreeNode class.  Is this correct?  Or should I be using HandleScope everywhere that Nan::New is called?  Or should it also be using EscapableHandleScope  rather than HandleScope since I actually want to be returning the values that are generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from the documentation markdown:

`Nan::HandleScope` - https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/scopes.md#api_nan_handle_scope :

Allocate a new Nan::HandleScope whenever you are creating new V8 JavaScript objects. Note that an implicit HandleScope is created for you on JavaScript-accessible methods so you do not need to insert one yourself.

`Nan::EscapableHandleScope` - https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/scopes.md#api_nan_escapable_handle_scope

Similar to Nan::HandleScope but should be used in cases where a function needs to return a V8 JavaScript type that has been created within it.

---

So, you were correct in using a `Nan::EscapableHandleScope` within `App::getData()`. However, I think this `Nan::EscapableHandleScope` within `App::getData()` could be moved to `TreeNode::getData( const TreeNode* pNode )`, since that is the function that actually creates the V8 Javascript type.

I don't think there's anything wrong with what you did here, I would just tend to keep the `Nan::HandleScope` / `Nan::EscapableHndleScope` closer to  (preferably within) the function that creates the object being returned.

Comment: The documentation says that HandleScope should be called whenever creating a new v8 object... so doesn't that mean that I should be calling it inside of each of my TreeNode::addProperty functions, inside TreeNode::getData too as you mentioned, and everywhere else that Nan::New is called??

Comment: You only create the object once, correct?  The function that creates the object should use a `Nan::EscapableHandleScope`.  This signifies to V8 where the object is scoped.  You only need one `HandleScope` ... The functions that call the function that returns EscapedHandleScopes do not need their own HandleScopes